# MYSQL - Group by two columns doesn't work

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have 2 tables, products and tags of this products - and I try to get products that have most joint tags with user tags.

So my code looks like:

```
SELECT 
    count(tags.id) AS best, 
    products.* 
from tags 
LEFT JOIN products ON products.idprod=tags.idprod 
where 
    ( tags.short = "one" OR tags.short = "two" OR tags.short = "four")
GROUP BY products.idprod, products.category
HAVING best > 2 
ORDER BY best DESC 
limit 8
```

And the problem is, that in my result products are grouped by product id (idprod), but not with category (there should be one product of a category only).

Any ideas?

Comment: What error(s) do you get? We don't know How many and which column(s) the table `products` has ...

Comment: No error, just multiple same column ids. 
Product table has 68 columns, so I won't write it all here. Problem is, that I can group by idprod, and by category, but not with both of them (no matter if I Group by idprod,category or category, idprod).

Comment: There is `products.*`(all the columns of the table) while only two of them provided within the GROUP BY expression. There should exist only products.idprod and products.category , which are non-aggregated, columns within the SELECT list.

Comment: Allready change that and still the same

Answer (score 0):

Columns in the group need to appear in the select

try this:

```
SELECT 
    products.idprod, products.category,count(tags.id) AS best
from tags 
LEFT JOIN products ON products.idprod=tags.idprod 
where 
    ( tags.short = "one" OR tags.short = "two" OR tags.short = "four")
GROUP BY products.idprod, products.category
HAVING best > 2 
ORDER BY best DESC 
limit 8
```

Comment: Nope, still have the same result